# How to always install app in a nested folder

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Using Inno Setup, I made an installer for a simple app. Here's what I want to do:

I want to always put the installed app in a specified folder inside of whatever directory the user selects (or doesn't select if they left the default), regardless if the user runs the installer via CLI or the wizard.

For example, say my .iss script looks like (only the relevant parts):

```
[Setup]
; other stuff like AppId here
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}

[Files]
Source: "C:\Desktop\Installer\WpfApp\{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Desktop\Installer\WpfApp\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Now let's say I want the app to always be installed inside of a folder called "SampleApps". This means regardless of what is entered in `DefaultDirName` or using the `DIR` parameter in the CLI, it'll first make a folder called `SampleApps` at that location (unless it already exists) and then put the app inside it.

I tried setting the `DestDir` like:

`Source: "C:\Desktop\Installer\WpfApp\{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "SampleApps\{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion`
but I always get the error `Setup was unable to create directory "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SampleApps\C:"`

Comment: "I want to always put the installed app in a specified folder inside of whatever directory the user selects" - why? (I am personally annoyed when an installer does this, because it is creating a directory that is unexpected.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Basically the system it's going on requires it be in that folder. Eventually there will be an "installer of installers", where multiple folders will be created inside the root folder to contain certain apps, regardless of where the root folder is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  I understand your question correctly, the `SampleApps` is a subfolder of `{app}`, so it's not `SampleApps\{app}`, but the other way around:

```
DestDir: "{app}\SampleApps"
```

Comment: Wow I think that did it. I feel so dumb. It's working perfect now. And for anyone curious, the installer by default will go to the root directory but you can set this property under the Setup section to change it:
`UninstallFilesDir="{app}\SampleApps\WpfApp"`